# ¿Por qué -0.0 no me da igual a 0.0?

Tags: java

tengo la siguiente prueba unitaria de [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) y descubrí algo muy interesante

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void BasicTest() {
     assertEquals("0.0!=-0.0",new Double(0.0D),new Double(-3.0D*0.0D));
    }
}
```

Me da el mensaje de error:

> 0.0!=0.0 expected:<0.0> but was:<-0.0>

¿Por qué 0.0 no es igual a -0.0 en Java?¿Qué formas existen de surcar este error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Por qué 0.0 no es igual a -0.0 en Java?

La respuesta está en la representación de bits del número. Utiliza este método:

```
 Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(x));
```

Donde `x` es una variable de tipo `double` para ver su representación en bits. Para los numeros 0.0 y -0.0 respectivamente, este es su resultado:

```
double x = 0.0d;
double y = -0.0d;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(x)) );
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(y)) );
```

Salida:

```
0
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Tal como puedes ver, los números 0.0 y -0.0 son **diferentes**. Y esto tiene sentido puesto que Java utiliza el [formato para coma flotante de IEEE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante) para la representación de `double`, donde el primer bit es para el signo.

> ¿Qué formas existen de surcar este error?

Súmale 0.0 al negativo y se resuelve el problema:

```
double x2 = 0.0;
double y2 = -0.0;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(x2)) );
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(y2 + 0.0)) );
```

Salida:

```
0
0
```